# Having issues uploading an image file to firebase using React-native/Expo

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo

Been trying to upload an image to firebase storage but haven't had any luck thus far. So when I pick an image from the library it displays it but after I try on pressing the post button it just gives me an error.

Here's the error I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBqqy.jpg

```
export default PostScreen = () => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);

  const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      width: 300,
      height: 400,
      quality: 1,
    });
    if (!result.cancelled) {
      console.log("user cancelled image");
      setImage(result.uri);
    }
  };

  const submitPost = async () => {
    const result = await uploadImage();
    console.log("Image Url: ", imageUrl);
  };

  const uploadImage = async (uri, imageName) => {
    const response = await fetch(uri);
    const blob = await response.blob();

    var ref = firebase
      .storage()
      .ref()
      .child("images/" + imageName);
    return ref.put(blob);
  };
```

Comment: have you seen this example? https://github.com/expo/examples/blob/master/with-firebase-storage-upload/App.js - notice the usage of XMLHttpRequest to get the blob, and the link to the relevant github comment about it

Comment: @brentvatne thanks for contributing. Everything works fine as it should but it uploads an image straight to firebase without any user approval. I can't seem to find a way on how to upload an image by pressing a button.